# Инлайновые редакторы

Tags: редактор

Кто работал с подобными инлайновыми редакторами, как показано в данном ресурсе: [инлайновые-редакторы](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/inline)

В дальнейшем планируется использовать данные редакторы для модификации контента на сенсорные устройствах вроде, как мультикассовые аппараты и сенсорные устройства.

Кто с подобным работал?

**Конкретные вопросы следующие:**

1. Какие элементы используются для редактирования контента в визуальном мгновенном режиме? (Редактирование контента в div блоках, либо в textarea, например. Или использовать реальные кнопочки buttons и submit, либо псевдокнопочки в которых редактировать из заголовки и функционал?)
2. Есть ли специальные js-движки или механизмы для формирования мгновенных результативных решений в области инлайновых редакторов (Надстройки над JQuery или объектные решения js заточенные под инлайновое редактирование контента).
3. Как реализовать технологию Drag и масштабирования блоков страницы ООПным методом средствами js и JQuery? (Смотреть, пример линка в начале вопроса).

Знания технологий мои следующие: PHP,JS,JQuery,HTML, IDE, Delphi.
Веб-технологии значительно предпочтительны, чем др.технологии.

Comment: Допустим я работал. В чем состоит ваш вопрос? Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @Kromster, да, расширил собственный вопрос, конкретизируя в выборе технологий, js фрейворков и плюшек для создания данных технологий редакторов.

Comment: По прежнему слишком расплывчато

Comment: @Kromster, добавил еще более подробную инфу, надеюсь, исчерпывающее спросил у знатоков в данной сфере разработок?

Comment: Реализаций куча, он сайта который в вопросе до многочисленных плагинов для jQuery, либо отдельных библиотек

Comment: Третий вопрос непонятен, плюс непонятно как он относится к первым двум